# goBack() with modified url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I've got a button that has an event binded to it, which makes the user go back to the previous page, using the **react-router-redux** `goBack()` function.

```
handleBackClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(goBack());
}
```

Let's say that the previous link was:

> https://mysite.fake/something?someParam=4&another=12

And the current link is something like:

> https://mysite.fake/test1?p1=true&p2=Banana

From the current link, I want to go back to the previous link but removing some parameters so i can go to:

> https://mysite.fake/something?another=12

How can I get the previous link, remove some params and redirect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript to get the last link in your the current tab document history.

```js
function goBack() {
  let next = document.referrer
  next = next.replace('someParam=4&','');
}
```

Then replace what you want to remove.